# Baire category theorem : Rationals

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the set of Rational numbers cannot be written as $\mathbb{Q} = \cap U_{n}$ when $ n = 0,1,2...$ and ${U_n}$ is a sequence of open subsets in $\mathbb {R}$. Hint: Use the Baire category theorem.

What i know so far is that $\mathbb {Q}$ is dense but nowhere dense, and the set $\mathbb {Q}$ is countable.

Any idea or hint about how to prove this statement will be appreciated thanks

Comment: How come a dense set can be nowhere dense? Other than this, do you agree that any set containing $\mathbb Q$ is dense?

Comment: What statement of the Baire Category Theorem do you know? Show that the sets $U_n$ must be dense, as are the open sets $V_q = \mathbb{R} - \{q\}$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Note that nowhere dense subset of $\mathbb R$ means that its complement has an empty interior. So $\mathbb Q$ is NOT nowhere dense.